# Custom Gradle task to build all projects without testing?

Tags: testing, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I know I can execute 'gradle build -x test', but is there a way to create a custom Gradle task, say, buildNoTests, which will build all of my projects but will completely ignore tests (don't compile/run them)?

I read that the 'assemble' task is not enough as it may miss other tasks which are not tests but are included in the 'build' task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in the root `build.gradle`

```groovy
allprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        def buildTask = tasks.findByPath('build')
        if (buildTask) {
           task buildNoTests {
               dependsOn buildTask
           }
           gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { TaskExecutionGraph graph ->
               if (graph.hasTask(buildNoTests)) {
                   def skipNames = ['test', 'compileTestJava', 'processTestResources', 'testClasses'] as Set
                   Collection<Task> testTasks = graph.allTasks.findAll { skipNames.contains(it.name) }
                   testTasks.each { it.enabled = false }
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried putting this into my root gradle.build file but it does nothing. Should it be different when put into the root gradle.build file? Here's the screenshot of the Gradle output (I cleaned before): http://i.imgur.com/w8WEwMX.png

Comment: That looks good to me! Everything's UP-TO-DATE and tests are skipped. Try `gradle clean buildNoTests` if you want it to actually execute the build from scratch

Comment: Just tried it - it does clean my specific project, but does not build them afterwards, maybe something it wrong with my gradle configuration?: http://i.imgur.com/GP107KS.png

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention: Gradle complains that the ':' after the dependsOn should be removed, and so I did. Second thing, here's the output of my execution (gradle clean buildNoTests) http://pastebin.com/3vmANFeM and last thing - If I put your code into one of the internal project's build.gradle, this specific project will build just fine without the test classes

Comment: Is there a way to make it work for all projects without inserting them specifically to each and every one of the build.gradle files? Adding it to 'allProjects' under the root file does not work.

Comment: Updated to add a `buildNoTests` task to every project which has a `build` task